# Is there a specific scope that I can use WL.Server.SetActiveUser?

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create an adapter based authentication in Worklight. I have added my Realm, Security test, and Login Module to the authenticationConfig file. I have tried to follow along with the modules provided by IBM.  I've copied the exact syntax and even hard coded values for the WL.Server.setActiveUser method. But I continue to get an error.  Is there a certain scope I can use this method in? Does anyone see or know where my error is?

I continue to get the follow error:

```
LOG: Request [login] 
LOG: Request [/apps/services/api/GPC2/android/query] 
LOG: response [/apps/services/api/GPC2/android/query] success: /*-secure-
{"responseID":"1","isSuccessful":true,"resultSet REMOVED LINE THAT CONTAINED DB RESULTS FOR     SECURITY
[/apps/services/api/GPC2/android/query] exception. 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'setActiveUser': object is null or undefined 

var lname= responseData.invocationResult.resultSet[0].somelastname;
var gpcid = responseData.invocationResult.resultSet[0].someid;
var fname = responseData.invocationResult.resultSet[0].somefname;
WL.Logger.debug("Login :: SUCCESS" + lname + " " + gpcid + " " + fname);  //this line does write the values to the log

//WL.Client.login("NotificationsRealm");
WL.Server.setActiveUser ("NotificationsRealm", {
userId: gpcid,
displayName: fname,
attributes: {
firstName: fname,
lastName : lname,
isUserAuthenticated: 1,
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [API documentation for WL.Server.setActiveUser](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_setactiveuser.html), it should be like this:

```
WL.Server.setActiveUser ("ACMERealm", {
    userId: "38017840288",
    displayName: "John Doe",
    attributes: {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "lastLogin": "2010-07-13 19:25:08.0 GMT",
    }
})
```

Looks like you are missing the double quotes for the attributes?

Comment: I've tried it with a hard coded string there and it doesn't work either.  The Srings are replaced with javascript variables so that the name can be dynamically populated from a SQL adapter.

Comment: I am referring to firstName, lastName and lastLogin; have you tried it like in the example?

Comment: Idan, Thanks for the response. Yes, I did try that.  I believe I have found my issue. There was a syntax error somewhere else in the code that was causing the problem.